# Jenkins Pipeline Job with Condition

Tags: if-statement, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a Jenkins pipeline. This pipeline is building three jobs (JobOne, JobTwo, JobThree). I am able to run the job with following code.

```
node {
   stage 'Stage 1'
   echo 'Hello World 1'
   build 'Pipeline-Test/JobOne'

   stage 'Stage 2'
   echo 'Hello World 2'
   build 'Pipeline-Test/JobTwo'

   stage 'Stage 3'
   echo 'Hello World 3'
   build 'Pipeline-Test/JobThree'
}
```

Now I want to put some condition in it. Example, when JobOne fails, the job has to restart once again. When JobTwo passes, want to run job again. And JobThree should run after a span of 10 mins after JobTwo completes. I am not sure how to make pipeline with this condition. I am new to Jenkins pipeline.

I checked few Jenkins WiKi page but could not find a proper way to implement if condition with above conditions. I tried below code just to check how 'if' condition can be implemented. But it fails.

```
node {
   stage 'Stage 1'
   echo 'Hello World 1'
   build 'Pipeline-Test/JobOne'
   post {
       always{
           build 'Pipeline-Test/JobOne'
       }
   }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, checkpoint, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, error, fileExists, git, input, isUnix, load, mail, node, parallel, properties, publishHTML, pwd, readFile, retry, sh, sleep, sshagent, stage, stash, step, teamconcert, timeout, tool, triggerRemoteJob, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:107)
```

Can someone please guide me through this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is definitely a learning curve with Jenkins Pipelines, so don't get discouraged :)

I recommend checking out [Jenkins' official documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) as well as the [Pipeline Steps Reference page](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/) to anyone getting started with Jenkins Pipelines.

FYI, `stage`s [without a block argument is deprecated](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-stage-step/#pipeline-stage-step); you should define `stage`s as follows:

```
stage('Name of Stage') {
   // code
}
```

Pipelines have a [retry step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-retry-code-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) that you can use to retry the `JobOne` build if it fails.

To wait 10 minutes between stage 2 and 3, you can use the [sleep step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-sleep-code-sleep).

`if` statements are written just like in Java, since [Groovy is actually compiled on a JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_(programming_language)).

```
if (animal == 'dog' || boolean == true) {
```

Combining each of these, I think this is what you can use:

```
node {
     stage ('Stage 1') {
          echo 'Hello World 1'
          retry(1) {
               build 'Pipeline-Test/JobOne'
          }
     }
     stage ('Stage 2') {
          echo 'Hello World 2'
          build 'Pipeline-Test/JobTwo'
     }

     sleep time:10, unit:"MINUTES"

     stage ('Stage 3') {
          echo 'Hello World 3'
          build 'Pipeline-Test/JobThree'
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Christopher!! :)  I will surely take a dive into it. I am completely new to this and was not finding a way out. Thanks again. I will try the steps you mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Christopher. JobOne is repeating fine. It works as expected but the tird job which has to run after a span of 10 mins, it is failing with following error:  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MINUTES for class: WorkflowScript. I am checking about this online. If you have any idea, let me know.

Comment: It works if I give only sleep(30). I mean if I pass only time and not unit. When I pass unit (MINUTES,MILLISECONDS), it throws error mentioned above.

Comment: Apologies, @Raji, I wrote the sample pipeline without double checking that it worked.  I edited my answer to show the appropriate `sleep` usage; I shouldn't have used parentheses in the earlier call.  Also, the units was supposed to be a String.